# Function inside renderItem in flatlist

Tags: react-native, render, react-native-flatlist

I have a flatlist and it's working fine, I'm trying to put a function inside the code that is rendering my item but it gives me an error, and i need to put the function there so i can read the item's properties, here is my code:

```
_renderItem ({ item, index}) {
     _shareText() {
          Share.share({
            message: item.name,
          })
        } 
return (
 <Button title="Share" onPress={this._shareText}/>
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, i can see that _shareText is not defined like a function in the component

```
_shareText(item) {
  Share.share({
    message: item.name,
  })
}

_renderItem({ item, index }) {
  return (
    <Button title="Share" onPress={() => { this._shareText(item); }} />
  );
}
```

Comment: it says 'can't find variable item'

Comment: it doesn't work onPress now, the sharer opens once i enter the screen and it doesn't open onPress

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't open onPress".  the share modal is opened?

Comment: I don't understand the error :/ i run this code and is ok, the share modal is opened. what do you want to do?

Comment: try bind functions inside comp constructor, I do not know if this could be

`this._renderItem = this._renderItem.bind(this);` or

`this._shareText = this._shareText.bind(this);`